# Vue crashes when binding input with large strings

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I've got this input that is bound with a property:

```
// in the template
<input type="text" v-model="someProp">

// in the script
export default {
  data() { return {
    someProp: ''
  }
}
```

The issue is that this input will be bound with a very long string (21k characters long). Upon copy/pasting the string into the input, the tab temporarily crashes in the following fashion:

- Can't scroll
- Text cursor stops blinking
- Window freezes
- Components that shouldn't be displayed appear

There seems to be some overprocessing when binding with large inputs. What can I change in my code to prevent the lag?

*And, if possible: is the overprocessing because of Vue or the browser?*

Comment: Does the property originate in the URL?  Is the issue in all browsers, or just 1?

Comment: This problem seems to only affect Codesandbox (at least that I've seen). Specifically, it occurs when pasting 21k chars in between quotes inside the `<script>` block of a `.vue` file. This happens across browsers (tested latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari). Cannot reproduce in Codepen, JSFiddle,  Stackblitz, or locally in VS Code.

Comment: @StevenSpungin Chrome (desktop and mobile) and desktop Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, some browsers optimize large text input only for `textarea` elements, but not for `input`. Doing the following change in my template prevented the tab from lagging:

```
// change this
<input type="text" v-model="someProp">
// to this
<textarea type="text" v-model="someProp"></textarea>
```

(with some additional styling, of course).

The issue seems to come from the browser and not from Vue, but that's all I can tell - additional input would be greatly appreciated!